# how to comment code containing close-comment delimiter

Tags: php

```
/*$a = $row['title'];
$b = preg_replace("/(?<=^|\n)[0-9\/-]+\s*/", "", $a);*/
```

Error: 
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in ... on line 14`

line 14 is the second line of the above code.

How to comment this?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, the regex works fine if uncommented

Comment: @puerto - no!. The problem is that your regex *contains* `*/` - prematurely ending the comment.

Comment: The `*/` in the regex is the end of the comment `*/`.  Try using a different delimiter in the regex.

Comment: The problem is that your regex has the `*/` in it.

Comment: Adding a second slash in the regex doesn't help, @DontVoteMeDown.

Comment: @MarkReed yeah, it had be any other char but not a slash tho haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can:

Change your regex delimiter

```
/*$a = $row['title'];
$b = preg_replace("#(?<=^|\n)[0-9\/-]+\s*#", "", $a);*/
```

Or use single line comment

```
//$a = $row['title'];
//$b = preg_replace("/(?<=^|\n)[0-9\/-]+\s*/", "", $a);
```

As you can see in the highlighted code, the regex contains the ending comment `*/` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Use single line comment i.e //

```
//$a = $row['title'];
//$b = preg_replace("/(?<=^|\n)[0-9\/-]+\s*/", "", $a);
```